# jQuery $.post redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

My auth system is working on rewrite level, so basically, every site that needs authentication is being redirected to login page. Is there any way to automatically redirect top.windows.location when ajax request is being redirected?

Comment: check if the request is an XMLHttpRequest on the serverside, and if so send something back to indicate that a redirect should happen, and use a regular javascript redirect in the always() function of the jQuery ajax method.

Comment: Doesn't this solution expose a security flaw? I could press F12 and skip the always stopping the redirect. This may be acceptable, just wanted to raise the risk. The problem is I cannot think of a better solution.

Comment: A possibly better solution is to not use ajax at all for this request. Instead, create a hidden form, add the inputs/values as needed, then submit the form, allowing the server to do the redirect.